# sorting list compared to other list in java

Tags: java, list, sorting, arraylist, collections

I have two list, say L1 and L2 with data as below:

```
   L1:
   {a, def2, a1;
    a, ert4, a2;
    i, ert4, a7;
    i, ght6, a8;
    a, def2, a3;
    o, ght6, a2;
    i, htf,  a8;
   }

   L2:
     {
      a1, 7;
      a2, 9;
      a3, 14;
      a4, 12;
      a5, 18;
      a6, 2;
      a7, 6;
      a8, 15
      }
```

I want to sort list L1 as per the the values of a1, a2 in list l2 in descending order. The output I want to be as:

```
{a, def2, a3;
 a, ert4, a2;
 a, def2, a1;
 i, ert4, a8;
 i, htf, a8;
 i, ght6, a7;
 o, ght6, a2
 }
```

I know we can use comparator for custom ordering, but I am not sure how to use it for different list.
Please tell me how I can do this.
Thanks

Comment: why do you need two lists? why not wrap the data into a class and have only one list of that class?

Comment: L1 is the input to the method. The input I am reading from a flat file, to a list which is L1. I want to arrange the data as per values of a1,a2,... in descending order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

firstly , L2 can be implemented using a map

```
HashMap<String, Integer> l2
```

then you can define a class for the element in L1

```
class Element implements Comparable<Element>{
     String value, label; // label is a1,a2,a3....; value is whatever other data you want to store
      int sequence;// used for sorting 
      public int compareTo(Element o)          {
  return this.sequence- o.sequence;
}
}
```

Given, that when you read L1 elements, just do

```
Element element = new Element();
element.value = "def2";
element.label="a1";
element.sequence = L2.getValue(element.label);

List L1 = new LinkedList();
L1.add(element);
```

Assuming L1 is also a collection, such as a list, you sort by

```
 Collections.sort(L1);
```

this will achieve your ordering purpose.

Comment: could you please elaborate below steps more:

Given, that when you read L1 elements, just do

element.sequence = L2.getValue(element.label);
Assuming L1 is also a collection, such as a list, you sort by

 Collections.sort(L1);